# Firebase after pod update missing CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist for GoogleToolboxForMac.framework

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

i made a pod update to update the firebase pods :

```
Installing Firebase (3.11.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (3.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (3.4.6)
Installing FirebaseDatabase (3.1.1)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Installing FirebaseStorage (1.0.5)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.7)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
```

Compiling is successful but when the simulator starts i get this messages:

> .....Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework did not have a CFBundleIdentifier in its Info.plist

I had some trouble with pod updates before and it worked after a new install of all pods :

```
pod deintegrate
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/
pod install
```

it usually worked, but not in this case. Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you post the contents of `.....Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/Contents/Info.plist`? In Finder, right click on the framework and press "Show Package Contents" to access the file.

Comment: That was a good hint. I had to delete an older built GoogleToolboxForMac.framework by hand in my ...Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ directory. In that Info.plist the CFBundleIdentifier was missing. Have not idea how this framework came to this place. Built Clean, pod deintregrate and all other attempts failed to delete it from that there.

Comment: Glad I could help! Did it work? If so, I will post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it did work, thx.

Comment: Yay! Could you please mark my answer as accepted so it is clear that the question is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the framework manually and try reinstalling it.